# Find common ancestor in SQL family tree WITH clause, table doesn't exist

Tags: sql, hierarchy, with-statement, family-tree

I looked at
[How to get lowest, common parent for 2 rows in recursive table (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608076/how-to-get-lowest-common-parent-for-2-rows-in-recursive-table-sql/608157)
where they suggest:

```
WITH
    hier1 (id, parent) AS (
    SELECT      id, parent
    FROM        table
    WHERE       id = @user1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      id, parent
    FROM        table l, hier1 h
    WHERE       l.id = h.parent
    ),
    hier2 (id, parent) AS (
    SELECT      id, parent
    FROM        table
    WHERE       id = @user2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      id, parent
    FROM        table l, hier1 h
    WHERE       l.id = h.parent
    )
SELECT  TOP 1 hier1.id
FROM    hier1, hier2
WHERE   hier1.id = hier2.id
```

and I changed to match my stuff:

```
WITH hier1(ID, motherID, fatherID) AS (
    SELECT ID, motherID, fatherID
    FROM persons
    WHERE ID = 3 -- example
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, motherID, fatherID
    FROM persons l, hier1 h
    WHERE l.ID = h.motherID OR l.ID = h.fatherID),
    hier2(ID, motherID, fatherID) AS(
    SELECT ID, motherID, fatherID
    FROM persons
    WHERE ID = 17 -- example
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, motherID, fatherID
    FROM persons l, hier1 h
    WHERE l.ID = h.motherID OR l.ID = h.fatherID)
SELECT hier1.ID
FROM hier1, hier2
WHERE hier1.ID = hier2.ID
LIMIT 1
```

but get:

> Table 'familytree.hier1' doesn't exist

It also says:

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)

I use MariaDB. [MariaDB documentation for WITH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/)

I tried looking for answers here:
[Oracle WITH CLAUSE not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801586/oracle-with-clause-not-working)

Seems like it works for some, and not for some..? I would appreciate some guidance!

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your DDL\DML and your expected outcome.

Comment: Hi. Yeah.. I don't know.. Made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589804/concept-to-find-common-ancestor-in-family-tree-sql-php